# id search works only for first element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block:

```
<div class="col-1-4 local_links">
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#user_profile">User Profile</a><div class="arrow-selected"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#dashboard">Dashboard</a>                  </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#change_password">Change Password</a> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
 </div>
```

[... some code ....]

```
<div class="col-3-4 local_responses">
   <div class="content full" id="user_profile" style="display: block;">
     <h2>settings :: User Profile</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="content full" id="dashboard">
     <h2>settings :: Dashboard</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="content full" id="change_password">
     <h2>settings :: Change Password</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

and some js which follows:

```
var local_links = $(".local_links");
var local_responses = $(".local_responses");

$(("a"),local_links).on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    local_links.find("div.arrow-selected").remove();
    $(this).parent().append('<div class="arrow-selected"></div>');
    $(".content", local_responses).animate({opacity: 0});
    $(id, local_responses).animate({opacity: 1});
});
```

If I do console.log(id) ... it shows the ID nicely... but it works only with first element. I know I am missing something trivial. Any thoughts?

Comment: IDs must be unique within the page, use a class instead.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `local_links.on("click", "a", function () {});` ? Where in your code does an element have the class "local_links"?

Comment: Your code sample doesn't show any anchor tags, it's difficult to comment.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar It does, they're in the table

Comment: Please show the generated HTML, not your template language (whatever you're using with the `{{ HTML::link('#dashboard', 'Dashboard') }}` syntax.)

Comment: edited ... this is how it looks after generation.

Comment: Where are the elements with the class "local_links"? I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with your binding

Comment: check now ... it looks like that... should have been added that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure everything's working correctly with your jQuery, but animating just the `opacity` doesn't magically change the `display` style from `none` to `block` or whatever the element's value is. I'm pretty sure you set a style for `.content` to have `display: none;`. When you animate the opacity, for the divs, their `display` stays as `none`, except the first one, because by default, it's overridden with `block`. Is there any reason you're animating `opacity` and not using something like `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut`?

Also, since you're storing an `id` in the `href`, there's no need to do something like `$(id, local_responses)`...just use `$(id)`. Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/SgwyM/

```
var local_links = $(".local_links");
var local_responses = $(".local_responses");

$(local_links).on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    local_links.find("div.arrow-selected").remove();
    $(this).parent().append('<div class="arrow-selected"></div>');
    $(".content", local_responses).fadeOut(400);
    $(id).delay(400).fadeIn(400);
});
```

And just to note, I changed the `on` binding because this way, it doesn't create an event handler for every `<a>` found - it creates one for each item in `local_links`, but is only executed for the selector `"a"`.

Comment: it does work with fadeIn/Out . Thanks Ian! I was actually not aware that opacity: 0 will not set the display: none. That did the trick.

Comment: @JacekDominiak Yep, 3 totally different styles for displaying an element - `display`, `visibility` and `opacity`. But all 3 are totally different and are unrelated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what behavior you're looking for, but posting your code unchanged to http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/hApgg/, I seem to get it working consistently for all three links.

I don't know why you write the parentheses wrapping the `"a"` below:

```
$(("a"),local_links).on("click", function(e){ //...
```

This would work equally well:

```
$("a", local_links).on("click", function(e){ // ...
```

but they're not hurting anything either.

So does this Fiddle duplicate your problem?  If not, then the problem is in code other than what you've posted.

Comment: That is really confusing at this stage. Indeed it does work on jsfiddle. I will review my code once again.

Comment: Yes you get the code working "correctly", but that's because you don't set the default style `display` to `none` for `.content`, which isn't specified in the original question but can be assumed. In that case, using `opacity` doesn't change anything about their `display`

Comment: @Ian: yes, that's quite possible.  It's just not clear what was missing.  I'm assuming that Jacek can use something like this to help figure out what's missing...